# Qt : coordinates with scrollbars?

Tags: qt, widget, scrollbar, qtablewidget

I have a widget `MyTable` that contains a `QTableWidget *table`.
This QTableWidget has a header for the columns `QHeaderView *header`, given by

```
table->horizontalHeaderView()
```

Ok, now I want to draw a widget in the section n°1 of the header.
Currently, I use :

```
QWidget *widget(header);
widget->setGeometry(header->sectionPosition(1), 0, header->sectionSize(1), header->height());
```

The widget geometry is updated each time the header geometry change and each time the `table->horizontalScrollBar()` is changed.

The problem is that the current version is buggy because the widget seems not to be drawn taking in account the scrollbar position. Maybe I have to change the coordinates when I do `widget->setGeometry`but I don't know how...

How to take in account the position of the scrollbar to draw my widget at the correct position ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solution found :

```
QWidget *widget(header);
widget->setGeometry(header->sectionPosition(1)-header->offset(), 0, header->sectionSize(1), header->height());
```